# Filling data fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a mini form where users can update add an important event. I want to add an edit button where the user can go and event that event. I have tried but the data fields is not being populated. I want to be able to present whatever the user had previously saved for the event in the form field whenever the user has pressed the edit button and then save the new data. Any help with this? I am providing an image plus a sample of my code.

form fields
[image: form fields]

edit button
[image: edit button]

```
<?php

if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('/index.php');
} 
//require_once '../core/init.php';
$user = new User();

$user->bring_li('date', array(
        'id'    =>  array(
            'operator'  => '!=',
            'value'     => '')
                ), 'd_order_o', 'cmp_r');

    $output ="";
//'.date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime($row->start)).'
    foreach ($user->variable_pro() as $row) {
         if($user->data()->access == 2) { 
        $output .= '<tr class="account_row" id="c_'.$row->id.'">
<td >

</td>
<td >

<span class="balance-btc ">
<span class="full">'.date('M d, y', strtotime($row->start)).' - '.date('M d, y', strtotime($row->end)).'</span>
</span></td>
<td >
<span >
<span class="full">'.$row->event.'</span>
</span>


</td>


<td class="settings">
<li><a href="#" onclick="Delete(\''.$row->id.'\')" >Delete</a></li>
<li class="tabItem tabAdd" onclick="switchTab(\'.tabAdd\', \'#add\', \'add\',\''.$row->event.'\')"><a class="tabActive">Edit</a></li>
</td>
</tr>';
         } else {
             $output .= '<tr class="account_row" id="c_'.$row->id.'">
<td class="clickable type">

</td>
<td class="clickable name">

<span class="balance-btc ">
<span class="full">'.date('M d, y', strtotime($row->start)).' - '.date('M d, y', strtotime($row->end)).'</span>
</span></td>
<td class="clickable balance">
<span class="balance-btc ">
<span class="full">'.$row->event.'</span>
</span>


</td>

<td class="settings"></td>
</tr>';
         }
    };


if(isset($_POST['date'])) {
            try {
                $user->create('date', array(
                    'event'     =>trim(Input::get('title')),
                    'start'     =>date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Input::get('start_date'))),
                    'end'   =>date('Y-m-d',strtotime(Input::get('end_date'))),
                    'add_by'    =>$username,
                ));


                    $user->bring_li('users', array(
                        'id'    =>  array(
                            'operator'  => '!=',
                            'value'     => ''),
                        'access'    =>  array(
                                'operator'  => '=',
                                'value'     => '2')
                                ), 'results');

        if($user->varcount()>0) {
            foreach ($user->variable_pro() as $row) {
```